# Disabling Firestore's network connection vs removing individual snapshot listeners when app enters background?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

We're given the option to disable Firestore's network connection using the `disableNetwork` method and we're also given the option to remove individual snapshot listeners using the `remove` method. When an app enters and exits the background, I've been in the habit of removing and re-adding listeners individually (so Firestore doesn't perform when the app is not in the foreground). However, is there any reason I shouldn't just disable/enable the network connection in one place when the app enters/exits the background versus the way I do it now? Is there any difference between the two approaches? Are there any negative consequences to this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more correct to deal with listeners individually in tandem with the views that are being populated with their data.

Disabling the network is likely to have side-effects that you'd rather not have in the future.  For example, if you ever wanted to do some simple background processing in your app while it's not on screen, shutting off the network altogether will get in the way of that.

Comment: Are there any side effects outside of my own inconveniences?

Comment: Maybe? You'll have to think through carefully what it means to disable the network for your app.  You'll notice that the product documentation doesn't suggest disabling the network for this reason.  The primary reason is to force all queries to use the local cache, which can save on document reads and latency for requests for single documents.  If you're not doing that, you're kind of coloring outside the lines.  But it's your call ultimately.